# How to add percent symbol with data inside column in highchart?

Tags: charts, highcharts, data-visualization, column-chart

I am using column highchart. Now I want % sign after my Data. Something like, if I have data value 7.18, I want to show it in 7.18% format. How can I do this? Please share with me if anyone has any idea.

[image]

My codes are below:

```
       $('#cagr2').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
             spacingBottom: -7,
             spacingTop:20
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },  exporting: { enabled: false },
         credits: {
      enabled: false
         },
        xAxis: {
            lineColor: 'transparent', 
            categories: ['']
        },
        yAxis: {

   lineWidth: 0,
   minorGridLineWidth: 0,
   minorGridLineWidth: 0,
   gridLineColor: 'transparent',
   lineColor: 'transparent',

   labels: {
       enabled: false
   },
   minorTickLength: 0,
   tickLength: 0,
              min: 0,
             title: {
                text: ''
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },

        legend: {
          enabled: true,
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'center',
            //x: -10,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: -5,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#ffffff',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: true
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b>',
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}',
            valueSuffix: ' %'
        },

        plotOptions: {
           series: {

                animation: {
                    duration: 7000
                }

            },

            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black',
                        fontSize: '18px'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Rate of return',
            data: [parseFloat(cagr)]
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do here is add the `format` or `formatter` attribute to your `dataLabels`.

**Example using `format`:**

```
column: {
    stacking: 'normal',
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
        style: {
            textShadow: '0 0 3px black',
            fontSize: '18px'
        },
        format: '{y} %', // your label's value plus the percentage sign
        valueDecimals: 2 // show your label's value up to two decimal places
    }
}
```

**Example using `formatter`:**

```
column: {
    stacking: 'normal',
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
        style: {
            textShadow: '0 0 3px black',
            fontSize: '18px'
        },
        formatter: function() {
            // numberFormat takes your label's value and the decimal places to show
            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + '%';
        },
    }
}
```

Here's how this will look:

[image]

I hope this helps!